# 401 Unauthorised Access error using Shopify API in VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, api, oauth, shopify

I'm trying to connect to the Shopify API in VB.NET and download some json order information, but every time I try I am getting a "401 unauthorised access" error. The code I am using to achieve this is as follows:

```
    'Develop API string to get orders
    Dim url As String
    url = "https://" & apikey & ":" & apipassword & "@" & domain & "/admin/orders.json"

    'Create new web service connection
    Dim ws As New WebClient()

    'Get json data from remote Shopify server
    Dim json_data As String
    Try
        json_data = ws.DownloadString(url)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Connection to the remote server failed! Please check your internet connection or contact the developer.", vbOKOnly, "Connection Failed")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

I understand there is another level of authorisation that Shopify uses (OAuth) but I do not know how to implement this. If anyone is able to help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding examples of shopify URL calls like that. Have you considered using their [.NET API](http://docs.shopify.com/api/libraries/net)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://shop.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json")

request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("apikey", "password")
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```